# How can I import this part model in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

I have to import the Vishay SMAJ33CA TVS diode model.

I found the spice model (subckt), but after autogenerating the symbol and trying to simulate it, I got errors.

This is the spice model:

```
*   SPICE3
* Bidirectional
.SUBCKT smaj33ca 1 2
DF 9 90 DFMOD TEMP = 25
.MODEL DFMOD D N = 2 IS = 5E-008 RS = 0.0195359
+ EG = 1.11 XTI = 3
+ CJO = 4.6E-010 VJ = 4.15897 M = 0.6 FC = 0.5
+ TT = 1E-008 TNOM = 25
* Leakage
RLF 9 90 3.51964E+007 RLMOD
RLR 1 9 3.51964E+007 RLMOD
.MODEL RLMOD R TC1 = 0 TC2 = 0 TNOM = 25
* Breakdown
RBD 90 4 1.85083
EBD 4 3 10 20 1
DBD 3 9 DBDMOD TEMP = 25
* Reverse
DR 9 1 DFMOD TEMP = 25
RBDR 1 94 1.85083
EBDR 94 93 10 20 1
DBDR 93 9 DBDMOD TEMP = 25
.MODEL DBDMOD D IS = 1E-015 N = 0.5 TNOM = 25
IBVC 0 10 0.001
RBVC 10 0 38650 RBVCMOD
.MODEL RBVCMOD R TC1 = 0 TNOM = 25
RBDX 20 23 1.85083
DBVC 23 22 DBDMOD TEMP = 25
DBVF 22 0 DFMOD TEMP = 25
IBVD 0 20 0.001
L1 90 2 1E-015
.ENDS
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import the model to your schematic with a .lib statement or by pasting it into the schematic as a spice command using the .op button (multi-line text will need to be formatted with + signs at start of new lines).

Then you can add a standard diode, ctrl-right click it and change the model to smaj33ca and the type from D to X. You have to change the type for subcircuits (.SUBCKT), for a straight .model you leave it as it was.

If you try this and still get errors you might have a bad model.

**Update** I've tried the model and am seeing errors  such as unrecognized parameters, so it looks like the model has some problems.

You might take a look at [this site](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm) and [this site](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/%7Egrober4/SPICE/SPICE_Decks/1st_Edition_LTSPICE/chapter3/Chapter%203%20Diodes%20web%20version.html) for more information on modelling diodes in LTspice. You'd have to find out what parameters like RLF and RBDR are supposed to do and try to come up with parameters that LTspice handles to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

Save the model as a (text) file and open it in LTspice. Right-click on smaj33ca and choose Create symbol. Edit it if you don't like the block appearance. Save it.

From now, it will be available as a new component under the Auto generated folder if you press F2 in your schematic.

[image]

Comment: Ok i knew this way, but then when i tried to simulate this component in a simple circuit, i got some errors, like unknown rlmod,dbdmod, rbvcmod ecc. why? thanks for the help

Comment: @Davide I'm getting the same thing, looks like maybe the model isn't supported by LTspice, where did you get it?

Comment: I found errors in the netlist, you have to change  3.51964E+007 RLMOD in   RLMOD 3.51964E+007  
and so on.

Comment: @Davide  Yes, the modelname needs to come before the value.  Good catch.